# null object reference when trying to show widget

Tags: android, string, android-studio, widget

i'm trying to show the simplest widget with just a few pictures, 
and everytime i try to show it the app crashes and i get null string refrence

```
Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String java.lang.CharSequence.toString()' on a null object reference
                                                 at java.lang.String.contains(String.java:2078)
                                                 at com.sec.location.nsflp2.a.a.c.b()
                                                 at com.sec.location.nsflp2.a.a.c.onForegroundActivitiesChanged()
                                                 at android.app.IProcessObserver$Stub.onTransact(IProcessObserver.java:55)
                                                 at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:573)
```

i switched all the tostrings, and string implementetions in the widget code, but it still doesn't help.

here is my
MainClockWidget:

```
public class MainClockWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                            int appWidgetId) {

    CharSequence widgetText = MainClockWidgetConfigureActivity.loadTitlePref(context, appWidgetId);
    // Construct the RemoteViews object
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main_clock_widget);
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, "hellow");

    // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
}

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
    }
}

@Override
public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // When the user deletes the widget, delete the preference associated with it.
    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        MainClockWidgetConfigureActivity.deleteTitlePref(context, appWidgetId);
    }
}

@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
}

@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context) {
    // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
}
```

}

MainClockWidgetConfigureActivity:

```
    public class MainClockWidgetConfigureActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String PREFS_NAME = "layout.MainClockWidget";
    private static final String PREF_PREFIX_KEY = "appwidget_";
    int mAppWidgetId = AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID;
    EditText mAppWidgetText;
    View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Context context = MainClockWidgetConfigureActivity.this;

            // When the button is clicked, store the string locally
//            String widgetText = mAppWidgetText.getText().toString();
            String widgetText = "Testings String";
            saveTitlePref(context, mAppWidgetId, widgetText);

            // It is the responsibility of the configuration activity to update the app widget
            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
            MainClockWidget.updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, mAppWidgetId);

            // Make sure we pass back the original appWidgetId
            Intent resultValue = new Intent();
            resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, mAppWidgetId);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);
            finish();
        }
    };

    public MainClockWidgetConfigureActivity() {
        super();
    }

    // Write the prefix to the SharedPreferences object for this widget
    static void saveTitlePref(Context context, int appWidgetId, String text) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0).edit();
        prefs.putString(PREF_PREFIX_KEY + appWidgetId, text);
        prefs.apply();
    }

    // Read the prefix from the SharedPreferences object for this widget.
    // If there is no preference saved, get the default from a resource
    static String loadTitlePref(Context context, int appWidgetId) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        String titleValue = prefs.getString(PREF_PREFIX_KEY + appWidgetId, null);
        if (titleValue != null) {
            return titleValue;
        } else {
            return context.getString(R.string.appwidget_text);
        }
    }

    static void deleteTitlePref(Context context, int appWidgetId) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0).edit();
        prefs.remove(PREF_PREFIX_KEY + appWidgetId);
        prefs.apply();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        // Set the result to CANCELED.  This will cause the widget host to cancel
        // out of the widget placement if the user presses the back button.
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);

        setContentView(R.layout.main_clock_widget_configure);
        mAppWidgetText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.appwidget_text);
        findViewById(R.id.add_button).setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);

        // Find the widget id from the intent.
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            mAppWidgetId = extras.getInt(
                    AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
        }

        // If this activity was started with an intent without an app widget ID, finish with an error.
        if (mAppWidgetId == AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) {
            finish();
            return;
        }

        mAppWidgetText.setText("testings");
    }
}
```

and my widget xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/the_nightmare_widget_background_resized"
        android:id="@+id/clock_background_image"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:rotation="0"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:id="@+id/clock_minutes_dial_image"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/the_nightmare_minute_pointer"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:rotation="-5"
        android:id="@+id/clock_hour_dial_image"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/the_nightmare_hour_pointer"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:id="@+id/clock_center_image"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/the_nightmare_center"
        />





    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/appwidget_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="#09C"
        android:contentDescription="@string/appwidget_text"
        android:text="@string/appwidget_text"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />




</RelativeLayout>
```

what could be the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

fixed it from some wierd reason it was just an error from when the image is too big.
resized the image > fixed the problem